# Cómo aplicar cláusula where en relación belongsToMany con Sequelize

Tags: javascript, nodejs, orm, sequelize.js

Hola estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación en node.js para administrar el acceso
a los menús registrados en mi base de datos. Quiero obtener el listado de `Menu` que tiene acceso determinado `Rol` , pero no entiendo cómo aplicar la cláusula `WHERE RolMenus.RM_acceso = 1`,.

Lo que he realizado es lo siguiente:

```js
const rol = await models.Rol.findByPk(
              1,
              {
                attributes: {
                  exclude: [
                    "Rol_state",
                    "createdAt",
                    "updatedAt",
                    "Rol_nombre",
                  ],
                },
                include: [
                  {
                    model: models.Menu,
                    as: "menus",
                    attributes: [
                      "Menu_principal",
                      "Menu_padre",
                      "Menu_nombre",
                      "Menu_icono",
                      "Menu_ruta",
                      "Menu_state",
                    ],
                  },
/*Para filtrar se me ocurre usar el modelo RolMenu pero devuelve el siguiente error:
EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: RolMenus is not associated to Role!
                  {
                    model: models.RolMenus,
                    where: {
                      RM_acceso: 1,
                    },
                  },
*/
                ],
              }
            );
```

> La consulta devuelve la información de los `Menus` que se encuentran relacionados con determinado `Rol`, pero ademas se adjunta la información de la tabla `RolMenus` y esto *no quiero mostrar* en mis resultados, solo quiero obtener los menus relacionados al Rol correspondiente filtrando el campo `RolMenus.RM_acceso = 1`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### La definición de la base de datos es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Definición de *associations*

```js
//NaN -> Roles & RolMenus & Menus
models.Rol.belongsToMany(models.Menu, {
  as: "menus",
  through: "RolMenus",
  foreignKey: "RM_IDrol",
});
models.Menu.belongsToMany(models.Rol, {
  as: "roles",
  through: "RolMenus",
  foreignKey: "RM_IDmenu",
});
```

### Deficinión de modelos

#### Menu.js

```js
const { sequelize } = require("../../config/db");
const { Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

class Menu extends Model {}
Menu.init(
  {
    Menu_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    Menu_principal: DataTypes.STRING,
    Menu_padre: DataTypes.STRING,
    Menu_nombre: DataTypes.STRING,
    Menu_icono: DataTypes.STRING,
    Menu_ruta: DataTypes.STRING,
    Menu_state: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: "Menu",
    timestamps: false,
  }
);

module.exports = Menu;
```

#### Rol.js

```js
const { Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const { sequelize } = require("../../config/db");

class Rol extends Model {}
Rol.init(
  {
    Rol_ID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    Rol_nombre: DataTypes.STRING,
    Rol_state: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    Rol_read: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    Rol_write: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    Rol_create: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    Rol_update: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    Rol_delete: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: "Role",
  }
);

module.exports = Rol;
```

#### RolMenu.js

```js
const { Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const { sequelize } = require("../../config/db");

class RolMenu extends Model {}
RolMenu.init(
  {
    RM_IDrol: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    RM_IDmenu: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    RM_acceso: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: "RolMenus",
    timestamps: false,
  }
);

module.exports = RolMenu;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo pensaría que falta la relación de `Rol` a `RolMenu`:

```
Rol.hasMany(RoleMenu, { as: "roleMenus" })
```

Y después si puedes hacer la consulta haciendo el include correspondiente como lo tienes.

Espero que ayude!

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, con esto se añadió un nuevo objeto `roleMenus ` pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Al final se resolvió agregando el siguiente parámetro `throw` a la consulta  de la siguiente forma:

```js
 const rol = await models.Rol.findByPk(
              1,
              {
                attributes: {
                  exclude: [
                    "Rol_state",
                    "createdAt",
                    "updatedAt",
                    "Rol_nombre",
                  ],
                },
                include: [
                  {
                    model: models.Menu,
                    as: "menus",
                    attributes: [
                      "Menu_principal",
                      "Menu_padre",
                      "Menu_nombre",
                      "Menu_icono",
                      "Menu_ruta",
                      "Menu_state",
                    ],
                    through: {
                      where: {
                        RM_acceso: 0,
                      },
                    },
                  },
                ],
              }
            );
```

Donde `RM_acceso` es el campo de validación en la tabla **RolMenus** que vincula la tabla **Roles** y la tabla **Menus**

Y este sería la respuesta final.:

```sh
{
    "rol_id": 1,
    "rol_admin": 1,
    "rol_nombre": "Administrador",
    "rol_state": 1,
    "rol_read": 1,
    "rol_write": 1,
    "rol_create": 1,
    "rol_update": 1,
    "rol_delete": 1,
    "menus": [
        {
            "Menu_principal": 1,
            "Menu_padre": 0,
            "Menu_nombre": "Configuracion",
            "Menu_icono": "fa fa-edit",
            "Menu_ruta": "/config",
            "Menu_state": 1,
            "RolMenus": {
                "RM_IDrol": 1,
                "RM_IDmenu": 2,
                "RM_acceso": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```